# Como hacer un SELECT FROM WHERE Multiple condiciones y usarlo en angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

**PHP**

```
<?php 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   

  date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");   
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sam", "", "sam")   

  or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');   
  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");   
  $request = json_decode($postdata);   
  $servicio_id = $request->servicio_id;
  $servicio_id2 = $request->servicio_id2;   

  $query = "SELECT rut,numero,servicio_id FROM Tickets WHERE servicio_id = $servicio_id OR servicio_id = $servicio_id2";  

  mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');   

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);   
  $array = array();   
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
  $array[] = array(   
   "rut" => $row["rut"],  
   "numero" => $row["numero"],  
   "servicio_id" => $row["servicio_id"]  
  );   
  }   

  echo $json_info = json_encode($array);   

?>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$http({  
      method: 'POST',  
      url: 'http://localhost/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaTickets.php',    
      headers: {  
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
          'Accept': 'application/json'  
      },  

      data:{  

        servicio_id: 38
        servicio_id2: 39
      }  

  })
```

.then(function(data) {

```
  var dat = data.data;
  $scope.tickets = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
    dat[i]
          var ticket = {
              numero: dat[i].numero,
              rut: dat[i].rut,
              servicio_id: dat[i].servicio_id
       };
              $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
}
});
```

**FÍN**

Comment: ¿cuál es el resultado esperado o qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: aparentemente tengo error de código y espero como resultado que al hacer la siguiente consulta me muestre todos los los datos del id 38 y 39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita los "." dentro de la consulta

```
$query = "SELECT rut,numero,servicio_id FROM Tickets WHERE servicio_id = $servicio_id OR servicio_id = $servicio_id2";
```